# CentOS7 で Maven を実行すると "JAVA_HOME environment variable is not defined correctly"

Tags: centos, maven

**実行環境**
CentOS 7.4

[Apache Maven 3.5 を CentOS 7 にインストールする手順](https://weblabo.oscasierra.net/install-maven-35-centos7/)

上記サイトを参考にしてMavenをインストールしたのですが、以下のようなエラーが出てコマンドの実行ができません。

```
The JAVA_HOME environment variable is not defined correctly
This environment variable is needed to run this program
NB: JAVA_HOME should point to a JDK not a JRE
```

.bash_profile には以下のように記述しています。

```
JAVA_HOME=/usr/java/default/
PATH=$PATH:/opt/apache-maven/bin
```

調べてみてもWindows環境での話ばかりだったのでよく分からず、こちらで質問させて頂きました。

ご回答頂けたら幸いです。

---

追記
ご指摘ありがとうございます。
以下に `java -version` 及び `which java` の結果を示します。

```
$ java -version
openjdk version "1.8.0_161"
OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_161-b14)
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.161-b14, mixed mode)
```

```
$ which java
/bin/java
```

Answer (score 1):

下記サイトを参考にして環境変数の設定を変更したら mvn コマンドが使えるようになりました。

[How to Install Apache Maven 3.5 on CentOS 7](https://www.vultr.com/docs/how-to-install-apache-maven-3-5-on-centos-7)

> ```
> JAVA_HOME=$(readlink -f /usr/bin/java | sed "s:bin/java::")
> ```

正直何故これで解決したのか分かっていないのでもう一度勉強し直したいと思います。